# Google auth2 .getCurrentUser() get the user token?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I'm using react in the front end and nodeJS in the backend.

I'm trying to have a google auth2 login flow from the front end.

Where can I get the token from a google auth2 login?

I see it in the response under `Zi.access_token` but it doesn't seem  to me to be the right way to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access properties such as `basic_profile`, `access_token`, the `Auth2` library provides a range of getter-functions that will allow you access the data in a predictable way.

For `access_token`, you should call the function `getAuthResponse()` on the  `GoogleUser` object returned from a successful login, this `GoogleUser` object will contain a key clearly labeled `access_token`

For `basic_profile`, [GoogleUser.getBasicProfile()](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergetbasicprofile) is provided

---

> I see it in the response under Zi.access_token but it doesn't seem to me to be the right way to get it.

You are right, and this is something perhaps the docs can mention.